# Обращение к матрице с помощью указателей C++

Tags: c++, указатели, матрицы

Вот матрица, заданная и обращаемая с помощью индексов, нужно чтоб индексов не было, только указатели.
Если кратко, то вводится матрица, производится сдвиг на 1 строку вверх (1 строка стаёт последней) и в новосформированной матрице ищется строка, в которой произведение элементов наименьшее. В общем, нужно сделать её с помощью указателей.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");

    const int n = 4, m = 3;
    int i, j, ind = 0, p = 1, P = 0;
    float matrix[n][m], matrix_2[n][m];

    puts(" Задайте матрицу");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");

    puts("\tЗаданная матрица");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%8.2f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i == 0)
                matrix_2[n - 1][j] = matrix[i][j];
            else
                matrix_2[i - 1][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    puts("\tСформированная матрица");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%8.2f", matrix_2[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            p *= matrix_2[i][j];
        }
        if (i == 0)
            P = p;
        else {
            if (p < P) {
                ind = i;
                P = p;
            }
        }
        p = 1;
    }

    printf("Номер строки, произведение елементов которой наименьшее - %d\n", ind + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: давайте, пожалуйста, не кратко

Comment: Самое простое - заменить `matrix[i][j]` на `*(*(matrix+i)+j)`...

Comment: Если у вас например двумерная матрица определённая как `int a[M][N];` либо через `int * a = (int*)malloc(M * N * sizeof(int));` то вместо индексации `int x = a[i][j];` можно делать тот же доступ но указателями через `int x = *(a + i * N + j);`.

Comment: Реализовал и поправил ваш код используя индексирование с указателями как вы просили, [вот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1223640/267338), посмотрите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас например двумерная матрица определённая как `int a[N][M];` либо через `int * a = (int*)malloc(N * M * sizeof(int));` то вместо индексации `int x = a[i][j];` можно делать тот же доступ но указателями через `int x = *((int*)a + i * M + j);`.

Ниже весь ваш код только с заменой всей индексации на указательную.

Для удобства я это индексирование через указатели реализовал у себя в коде ниже через `AT(...)` макрос, увидите как его использовать по коду. Если согласно поставленной задаче нужно именно оставить в виде указателей, то просто замените использование `float x = AT(a, float, m, i, j);` на выражения вида `float x = *((float*)a + i * m + j);`.

Конечно раз это С++, то я бы мог написать вместо AT удобную шаблонную inline функцию. Но раз у вас задача перейти от индексации к указателям, т.е. чисто низкоуровневый Си подход, то думаю вам шаблонные функции и другие фишки С++ точно не нужны.

Код ниже использует AT, но я сделал [по этой ссылке](https://tio.run/##zVVBaxNBFL7Pr3hsKcwkm9JNW62kLZRSxEssacVDW5Z1s7ETdidLdgOKBGIV8SB49OTBfxDExVRj/Auzvyi@mU1iN7ZWSg5OWN7Me2/mfd/Mx4sbhiXXd8TT8Xip7jW48MDeqx3Zh/t7j2r7dvWh/Xi3Vn1QvX9Ilrhw/U7dg60orvPWytlO3uXzJ8pHpufsHlHHhNgEt@VHJnATmgxogVIaF5jDoAiUMygAVXG9bDLGCOEihsDhgjJ4QQBH9DyKvYAa7pkbglXesAxWITritkQUg9ogYBvWTQjQrFV0THlVTaws6uheNSFEY5lwoFZZUsNvOapa3ObPjsXpcXBqTlZ2OVtPKoWdOKIGyA@yL7/gd5GeywTkUPbT87QnB@mb9JWCpQ9ttZGaLgIctkCgKRanbGYZzSyjiRkBmnyG5u06okGN5YZhAtVICywDh5fF8eYCtM1JUTW6s1kGdwqoS/K@S8uTeEbpB/766fscKdlfNKmwjQ@jWG2ulBUx1MP11G7L7WYoMzoCSmApSjsZtVJpHjFv6EwMs5xfjXn0dlnpWJ/JZiywyl9ZVnLHen7k/WMdfts63cnV5YXwKX0tR/juQ3z5nhzJz/@NKDTdBcliEXChsH0TxqsgXqck1ZDC3xuUAq7QYIh4DuahZJ1O9Tde@SMwd24ezKWbU22xkpPE5D3kR5TBUCZpD9KX@vlH8pscmCB/6vlAfkWVJNg@EtTJQHXERH7Hb6gc2CJRRIA7Rmqqd1yAEhSmZhnv0rdoE9Txcv1EGFmvLqKoMzhtL@60hWrWXTIer8MG3CEWlGGN3IVNuEesVbAs/Ev4BQ) вариант кода полностью без AT, чисто указатели как вы просили.

[Попробовать код ниже онлайн!](https://tio.run/##xVRRaxNBEH7fXzFcqdwlm9JLW62kKZRSxJdY0ooPbTnOy8VuuNscuQsoEohVxAfBR5988B8E8TDVGP/C3i@Ks3uXmIu1Kgbc49jd2dmZ79v5GCcISo5n80eTyUrDbTLugrVfP7aODvbv1w@s2j3rwV69drd254isMO543YYLO2HUYO218928yWMPpY1M4@wd6zaFiILT9kIKjELLAL2g63pUMGwDiqAzAwqgy3O1bRmGQQjjEfg247oBTwngCJ@EkevrmnPuBGCWt0zNqBB14rR5GIG8wKEKmxR8nDYq6kxaZU7MzBtoXqcQ4GRSOJS71KnptW2ZLeqwxyf87MQ/o9nOKqf7LFPQjUJdA/FWDMRH/C@TCxGDGIlBcpH0xTB5mTyXsFTQdgepqSTAYAc4TsXilM3Mo5V6tNDDxynvoXg7Nm/q2mpTo3ADXzMFRlPQiDN70yyrHL3ZKsU7RdQjedvc9jSacfqK3yB5k2MlBstmFXSwMpLW9lpZMls@sd/jmHHhUAJT8tlNeZVKi3BZU3nisZGzyzGDbpXnwaugSu3Va9hVcuFcL3T/ND77y/i97KnyVX@fvBBjLPIIy9wXY/Hh/ytggeY/a2AZWKFQvRbgVfh@pRnZeIIfF2TNr1BbgGAOF3GkHU32MVb56WAhbh7M3LPJ9lfJiSGrhHiHAhiJOOlD8kwVfiw@iyEF8U2th@IT6iPGLhGjQoay88XiC/4jacBWiPIBvDGWS3XjEqSU0DX1eJ28wjlG4a42TrmW9uQimNnzddyo2@GyKffIZLIJW3CTmFCGDXILtuE2MdfBNLH1fwc)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define AT(a, t, cols, i, j) (*(((t*)a) + (i) * (cols) + (j)))

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");

    const int n = 4, m = 3;
    int i, j, ind = 0, p = 1, P = 0;
    float matrix[n][m], matrix_2[n][m];

    puts(" Задайте матрицу");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            scanf("%f", &AT(matrix, float, m, i, j));
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");

    puts("\tЗаданная матрица");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%8.2f", AT(matrix, float, m, i, j));
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i == 0)
                AT(matrix_2, float, m, n - 1, j) = AT(matrix, float, m, i, j);
            else
                AT(matrix_2, float, m, i - 1, j) = AT(matrix, float, m, i, j);
        }
    }

    puts("\tСформированная матрица");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%8.2f", AT(matrix_2, float, m, i, j));
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            p *= AT(matrix_2, float, m, i, j);
        }
        if (i == 0)
            P = p;
        else {
            if (p < P) {
                ind = i;
                P = p;
            }
        }
        p = 1;
    }

    printf("Номер строки, произведение елементов которой наименьшее - %d\n", ind + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Вход:

```
Задайте матрицу
4 5 6
1 2 3
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Выход:

```
    Заданная матрица
    4.00    5.00    6.00
    1.00    2.00    3.00
    7.00    8.00    9.00
   10.00   11.00   12.00

    Сформированная матрица
    1.00    2.00    3.00
    7.00    8.00    9.00
   10.00   11.00   12.00
    4.00    5.00    6.00

Номер строки, произведение елементов которой наименьшее - 1
```

Comment: Код по ссылке у вас также с AT

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Нет, там всё верно, AT просто в этой версии кода задефайнен, но не используется, оставил для примера если захочется использовать, но всюду в коде полноценные указатели только.

Comment: У меня был немного другой вариант сдвинуть строку вверх [тут](https://pastebin.com/5zaiizxx)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Тоже подходящий вариант, кстати хороший! Но это для двойных указателей типа `float **`, но если исходить из кода OP, то там использовался `float matrix[N][M];` а это двумерная матрица в С/С++, которая идентична `float *` с выделенным блоком памяти размером `N * M * sizeof(int)`, т.е. многомерная матрица в С++ это просто одномерная но с памятью равной размеру всей матрицы. Т.е. я к тому, что если OP использовал двумерную матрицу, то я далеко от его кода не отходил и тоже использовал у себя двумерную только через работу с указателями, т.е. сделал минимальное изменение.

Comment: Я так понял автор хотел полностью отказаться от ```[][]``` в пользу ```float **```

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Нужно его спросить. У него не однозначно вопрос трактуется. Он просто сказал что мол хочу указатели. А хотел ли он двойной или одинарный указатель это не сообщал. У меня и у вас оба варианта сделаны с указателями, т.е. и мой и ваш вариант подходит под понятие "с указателями". Так что будем ждать от него уточнения.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Если хотите можете оформить ваш вариант ответа с `float **`, это совсем другой вариант чем мой, так что вполне можно отдельный ответ под него создать. Т.к. хотя бы там алгоритмы сдвига будут уже другие. Если хотите ответ оформлять.

Comment: @Arty и в правду я не уточнил вопрос, извиняюсь, просто оба варианта мне подходят (как одинарные так и двойные), т. к. главное было заменить индексы. Сам указатели не люблю (сложно мне даются), но пришлось поменять индексы на указатели. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler за ваш вариант тоже отдельное спасибо, опять же извиняюсь за не уточнение, просто мне подходили оба варианта.

Comment: @Aeros всегда пожалуйста) советую присмотреться к некоторым частям моего варианта, т.к. как я написал в комментарии, некоторые вещи будут работать оптимальнее в таком варианте, и подходят лучше для вашей конкретной задачи. Если конечно Вас интересует процесс, а не только результат :)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler да, я видел, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Когда звездочки нравятся больше, чем скобочки, или вариант с двойным указателем:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 3
using namespace std;

void shift(float** matrix, int rows)
{
    float* row = *matrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
        *(matrix+i) = *(matrix + i + 1);
    *(matrix + rows - 1) = row;
}

void print(float** matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << setw(10) << *(*(matrix + i)+j) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void input(float** matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            cin >> *(*(matrix + i) + j);
}

int leastMulti(float** matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    int idx = 0;
    float min = numeric_limits<float>::max(), multi;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        multi = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            multi *= *(*(matrix + i) + j);

        if (multi < min)
        {
            min = multi;
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    return idx;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    float** matrix = new float* [ROWS];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        *(matrix + i) = new float[COLS];
    input(matrix, ROWS, COLS);
    shift(matrix, ROWS);
    print(matrix, ROWS, COLS);
    cout << "Номер строки с наименьшим произведением: " << leastMulti(matrix, ROWS, COLS) + 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Стоит отметить, что обращение `*(*(matrix + i) + j)` - не обязательное, а лишь навеяно неполным вопросом автора. К `float **` типу можно все также обращаться и с помощью `matrix[i][j]`.

Преимущество, кстати, такого подхода в том, что вы можете не использовать дополнительный массив для сдвига, а двигать строки прямо внутри имеющейся матрицы, меняя местами указатели на первый элемент строки, что занимает и меньше памяти, и меньше операций (см. метод `shift`).